# How to change decryption time of KeePassXC database?

Tags: keepassxc

How to change decrypt time of KeePassXC database after beng created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done from [Database Settings](https://keepassxc.org/docs/KeePassXC_UserGuide.html#_database_settings), in the “Security” section, in the “Encryption Settings” tab:

[image: KeePassXC Encryption Settings, showing the Decryption Time configuration slider]